# code coverage very low inspite of multiple tests

Tags: ruby, code-coverage, simplecov

I have a simple ruby file that returns the [largest integer](https://github.com/alaghu/Algorithms/blob/master/lib/Algorithm/largest_integer.rb), which has corresponding [spec](https://github.com/alaghu/Algorithms/blob/master/features/largest_integer_spec.rb) file which, I believe, should go through different part of the code.However, in RubyMine, using simplecove gen, it is [reporting](https://github.com/alaghu/Algorithms/blob/master/exportToHTML/index.html) only 28.57 % covered (
7 relevant lines. 2 lines covered and 5 lines missed. ).

Could you please help me understand why my tests are missing these (5) lines.

Thanks for your help

Comment: How are you running the tests?

Comment: Hi Zach , I used Ruby Mine IDE to run the code coverage report. I run the rspec from the IDE as well , which all passed.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with how RubyMine runs tests, but it sounds like it is running them all individually instead of as a suite (plus, in my experience, SimpleCov can be incredibly picky about how the test environment is setup). Have you read [RubyMine's page on SimpleCov setup](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/code-coverage.html)?

Comment: Hi Zach,Thank you for the pointer. I tried running rspec from cmd line`ani:Algorithms/ (master*) $ rspec features/largest_integer_spec.rb                                                                                  [18:31:02]
....

Finished in 0.00178 seconds
4 examples, 0 failures
Coverage report generated for RSpec to /Users/ani/RubymineProjects/Algorithms/coverage. 7 / 7 LOC (100.0%) covered.` Found that worked. Now I need to debug the integration/settings with Ruby mine.